# Where can I catch an exception?

Tags: haskell, time, haskell-stack

My code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module UserData where

import           Control.Exception
import           Data.Either
import           Data.Maybe
import           Data.Time         (getCurrentTime)
import           Data.Time.Clock
import           Data.Time.Format

import           Types

round' :: NominalDiffTime -> Integer
round' mark
    | mark < 0 = 0
    | mark2 > 100 = 100
    | otherwise = mark2
    where mark2 = round mark

supportedCities :: [City]
supportedCities = [Aragatsotn .. Yerevan]

getUserData :: IO (Either String (UTCTime,City))
getUserData = do
    date         <- getDateFromUser
    cityFromUser <- getCityFromUser
    if | isLeft date         -> return $ Left "error"
       | isNothing cityFromUser -> return $ Left "error"
       | otherwise      -> let [realDate] = rights [date] in return $ Right
```

(realDate, fromJust cityFromUser)

```
getDateFromUser :: IO (Either String UTCTime)
getDateFromUser = do
  Prelude.putStrLn "Пожалуйста, укажите дату для прогноза в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД:"
  currentTime <- getCurrentTime
  date        <- Prelude.getLine
  let dayFromUser = parseTimeOrError True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" (date ++ " 12:00:00") :: UTCTime
  case dayFromUser of
    validDay -> do
          let differenceInNominalDiffTime = diffUTCTime validDay currentTime
              secondsInDay = 86400
              differenceInDays = round' $ differenceInNominalDiffTime / secondsInDay
          if differenceInDays >= 0 && differenceInDays <= 5
              then return $ Right validDay
              else return $ Left "asdasd"

getCityFromUser :: IO (Maybe City)
getCityFromUser = do
    Prelude.putStrLn "Пожалуйста, укажите один из этих марзов:"
    print [Aragatsotn .. Yerevan]
    cityFromUser <- Prelude.getLine
    let cityAsString = Prelude.map show supportedCities
    if cityFromUser `elem` cityAsString
       then return $ Just (read cityFromUser :: City)
       else return Nothing
```

This code working.

I getting error

But as far as I understand the parse function, parseTimeOrError returns an exception. How and where should I catch this exception?

That is, instead of an exception, I need to show some string

like "sorry,your data is incorrect"

Answer (score 1):

The easiest change to your program is to use [parseTimeM](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.2/docs/Data-Time-Format.html#v:parseTimeM) instead of `parseTimeOrError`.

`Maybe` is one of the possible types that can be filled in for `m`, so you can write:

`parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2018-10-23 11:41:20" :: Maybe UTCTime`

In your program, `validDay -> do` can change to `Just validDay -> do`, and GHC will infer the `Maybe`, so you won't need the explicit type signature that I gave above.

Comment: I'm use parseTimeM,but i'm dont getting error 
   let dayFromUser = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" (date ++ " 12:00:00") :: Maybe UTCTime
  case dayFromUser of
    Nothing -> return $ Left "asd"
    Just validDay -> do

when the user enters nonsense, I want the program to immediately die and give an error. But it continues to work.
And I get an error from this line already isLeft date         -> return $ Left "error"

Comment: Please edit your question with the revised code & include the error message that you are now getting.